# Get EditTextPreference value

Tags: android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences, edittextpreference

I've created an EditTextPreference and now I want to get the value from any other activity. I've been trying a lot of things but I cannot get it working. Where is this value stored? How can I retrieve it?

EDIT: I want to get the value from a different activity, not the `Preferences` activity.

`settings.xml`

```
<EditTextPreference
    android:title="EditText1"
    android:key="edit1"
    android:defaultValue="0"
    android:dialogIcon="@drawable/fleetespiar"
    android:inputType="number" />
```

`Settings.java` **(How to do this in a different activity)**

```
Preference edit1= findPreference("edit1");
EditTextPreference editt1 = (EditTextPreference) edit1;

System.out.println(String.valueOf(editt.getText().toString()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your value will be stored in a shared preference file.

Check my little example below:

1. Create a *xml* directory inside the *res* directory (resources) of
   your android project.
2. Inside your new *xml* directory you must create a preference.xml file wich will contains your EditTextPreference.

   ```
       <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
           <EditTextPreference
               android:dialogTitle="My preference"
               android:key="pref"
               android:summary="Enter Your Preference"
               android:title="Edit Text Preference" />
       </PreferenceScreen>
   ```
3. Now create your *Preferences* class  which extends **PreferenceActivity**.

   ```
       import android.content.SharedPreferences;
       import android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener;
       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.preference.EditTextPreference;
       import android.preference.Preference;
       import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

           public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity {

           @Override
           protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
           }
       }
   ```
4. Use a **SharedPreference** object to insert and get your String value.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. I know how to do it, I know how to get the value when I create the `SharedPreference` and I store it where I want. The problem is that this value is saved automatically. `I've tried with getDefaultSharedPreferences()` but no luck... Maybe the question is not as self-explainable as I tought. Sorry.

Comment: @KrLx_roller, you might take a look at [this](http://android-er.blogspot.pt/2010/08/edittextpreference.html) and [this](http://androidpartaker.wordpress.com/tag/edittext-preference-summary/) references. I think they can help you a lot.

Comment: Thank you! I Googled and I found the second webpage, not the first one. It's what I was looking for. But it's strange... I did exactly what the example show with no luck... Maybe I forgot something... Thank you! I'll try it now!

Answer (score 2):

First you need to create an instance of `SharedPreferences`, then you can call `getString()` on it, specifying the key for the value.

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. I know how to do it, I know how to get the value when I create the `SharedPreference` and I store it where I want. The problem is that this value is saved automatically. `I've tried with getDefaultSharedPreferences()` but no luck... Maybe the question is not as self-explainable as I tought. Sorry.